# GWT image get from server

Tags: gwt

when I implemented as given here but for not working 
my implementation is 
ServerSide:

```
File f = fileFromDatabase // from database the fileName is india.png
DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
din.readFully(data);
din.close();
String base64 = Base64Utils.toBase64(data);
String[] s = filename.split("\\.");   

base64 = "data:" + "india/png" + ";base64," + base64;
or
base64 = "data:image/png;base64," + base64;

return base64;

clientSide:

 imageService.getImageData(new AsyncCallback() {
    @Override  
     public void onSuccess(String imageData) {    
        Image image = new Image(imageData);    
         Canvas.addChild(image);
         //this Canvas class addItem into com.smartgwt.client.widgets.Window
      }
     @Override 
     public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {

     }
}
client side imageData stirng is <image class="gwt-Image src=sume big string starts with "data:image/png;base64,someSting......>"
```

eventhough client side could not see the image.

Please clear my doubt
Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you using the canvas? If you are drawing the image to a canvas, it has to be attached to the DOM before you can use it. Your encoding to base64 looks correct.

Comment: Thanks for   Response                                                                                       myClass extends Canvas{ all client side code here finally just this.addChild(image)  } i dont know whether it is drawing or adding a component. but i get image from local drive I can see the image on canvas.

Comment: You will still see the image because it will still get added to the DOM but you will still need to attach a LoadHandler if you plan on doing anything else with it. For my purpose, I had to attach it to the DOM hidden, wait for it to load, then draw it to a canvas.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the base64 string from the server you need to add a load handler on the image in the DOM. The way I've done it is to attach it to the DOM and hide it as in the below code.

```
/** get events preview from server, attach to the DOM and store in 'preview'
 * @param handler option to pass a custom load handler
 */
private void get_preview(LoadHandler handler) {
    final LoadHandler load_handler = handler;

    server.getPreviewImage(user, data, new AsyncCallback<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            log.info("getPreviewImage: " + error);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String result) {
            preview = null;

            if (result != null) {
                ImageElement ie = doc.createImageElement();

                preview = Image.wrap(ie);
                preview.setVisible(false);

                doc.getElementById("imagedummy").removeAllChildren();
                doc.getElementById("imagedummy").appendChild(preview.getElement());

                // add load handler to DOM image before being able to use

                if (load_handler == null) {

                    preview.addLoadHandler(new LoadHandler() {
                        @Override
                        public void onLoad(LoadEvent event) {
                            display_preview();
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    preview.addLoadHandler(load_handler);
                }

                preview.setUrl(result);
            }
        }
    });
}

/** Displays the preview on the canvas.
 * Resizes canvas if necessary and sets zoom
 */
private void display_preview() {
    EventSize size = data.getEventSize();

    canvas.canvas.setCoordinateSpaceWidth(size.width);
    canvas.canvas.setCoordinateSpaceHeight(size.height);

    float zoom = Float.parseFloat(preview_zoom.getSelectedValue());
    canvas.canvas.setPixelSize((int)(size.width * zoom), (int)(size.height * zoom));

    if (preview != null) {
        ImageElement elem = ImageElement.as(preview.getElement());
        canvas.canvas.getContext2d().drawImage(elem, 0, 0);
    }
}
```